# Calling function from JavaScript confirm box

Tags: javascript, code-behind

I have a confirmation box. I want to call a function if the user clicks OK on the box. The code is as follows.

```
Dim message As String = " An Assessment for this date already exists. To create another one for this date click OK OR else click CANCEL to go back to Assessment History. "
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
sb.Append("if (confirm('")
sb.Append(message)

sb.Append("')){ ") 

sb.Append("}")
sb.Append("else{")
sb.Append("window.location = 'SA.aspx?PID=" & Request("PID") & "';")
sb.Append("}};</script>")
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
sb.Append("')){ ") 
sb.Append("yourFunction();") 
...
```

(Provided you're talking about a JavaScript function, of course.)

Comment: Actually i am trying to call a VB function that i have defined with in the document

Comment: You can't! All vb functions are already gone when js runs. Look into Ajax.